# How to filter out hidden products in Woocommerce using array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, woocommerce

I have an array, but I am unable to add in a last bit, where I want to filter out the products, that are hidden, which doesn't seem to be working.

So firstly I have tried to print out all variables using `get_defined_vars()` which printed out all variables as expected. Then I have found the part of array I was interested in

```
Array ( [name] => Test1 
        [slug] => test1 
        [date_created] => WC_DateTime Object ( 
            [utc_offset:protected] => 0 
            [date] => 2018-03-06 11:29:10.000000 
            [timezone_type] => 3 
            [timezone] => Europe) 
        [date_modified] => WC_DateTime Object ( 
            [utc_offset:protected] => 0 
            [date] => 2018-05-30 22:33:49.000000 
            [timezone_type] => 3 
            [timezone] => Europe) 
        [status] => publish 
        [featured] => [catalog_visibility] => hidden
```

which I thought is all I need, so I have tried to insert into the array this line:

`'catalog_visibility' => 'visible',` which didn't work. Do I have to include also the [featured] element to make it working?

Doing `echo $product->visibility;` prints out, if the product is hidden or visible.

I have this array:

```
$args = array(
     'post_type' => 'product',
      'orderby' => 'rand',
      'posts_per_page' => 1,
      'product_cat' => 'c_pubescens',
      'post_status' => 'publish',
      'meta_query' => array(
           array(
               'key' => '_stock_status',
               'value' => 'instock'
       )
  )
);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
```

I am lost in this. Why does it print the status, if I do `echo $product->visibility;` but if I do `echo $product->catalog_visibility;` (which is in the array) it doesn't return anything? And mainly, how do I make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, found answer for myself. Forgot to post it, so here it is.

```
$args = array(
     'post_type' => 'product',
     'orderby' => 'rand',
     'posts_per_page' => 1,
     'product_cat' => 'c_pubescens',
     'post_status' => 'publish',
     'tax_query'    => array(
           array(
              'taxonomy'         => 'product_visibility',
              'terms'            => array( 'exclude-from-catalog', 'exclude-from-search' ),
              'field'            => 'name',
              'operator'         => 'NOT IN',
           ),
      ),
     'meta_query' => array(
         array(
             'key' => '_stock_status',
             'value' => 'instock'
   )
```